# How to represent uml diagram when class A variables are initialized via class B

Tags: uml

I have class A with  static variables that are initialized via setter methods from Class B, Class B only use these static methods from class A to initialize it.
How to represent this in uml ? should class B be the one using class A although it actually doesn't need class A in its functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just draw a dependency from `B` - - - > `A`. That's showing the correct relation between both.

Comment: I mean that by looking at the main picture, class A is the one using class B for initializing its variables and that's achieved  by making class B call class A methods, so which class is using the other in this case?

Comment: @david What do you mean, when you say “Class A is using Class B for initializing its variables“? As far as I understood your question, Class A doesn‘t even know Class B. It may need its attributes (that is the correct UML term) to be somehow initialized to be ready to be used, but this seems to be the responsibility of the client of Class A, who might then choose to use Class B to do it.

Comment: Also what is that _main picture_  you mention?

Comment: okie I will try to explain that in more details according to my case, It's android application, I have ImageProcessing class that contains static variables that are initialized through setters from class B. But class B doesn't use any of the class Image processing functionalities, like getting number of circles in a picture, etc.  class B only uses the setter methods of  Image processing class.
What I mean by looking at the main picture, is that class Image processing is one using class B for initializing its variables not otherwise as @qwerty_so answer indicates.

Comment: Does ImageProcessing call class B in order to get itself initialized, or does B take the initiative to initialize ImageProcessing? Are you able and willing to modify ImageProcessing in order to improve the app's architecture?

Comment: B takes the initiative, Yeah I tried actually, but I couldn't modify my code. ImageProcessing needs to access the application resources to initialize its variables , but since it's android application, class B which is an android activity, is the one that can get the resources for ImageProcessing class.
And to make it more complicated, the classes that use the ImageProcessing functionalities are not activities, so they can't initialize its static variables.

Comment: In that case, I would recommend to draw a dependency from B to A, as qwerty_so wrote, and either add a note saying 'only for initialization' or add a stereotype ≪initialize≫ (but don't forget to define that stereotype somewhere, because it is not a standard UML stereotype).